# Dependency Injection Container: Multiple instances of a single class

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am just starting with Dependency Injection Containers, and I am having a problem that makes my code messy. Let's take an example: I have a simple Container class that manages multiple services, a service can be "marked" as shared so it can only make one single instance.

So for example, I will make a simple (It's not the one I actually use) dependency injection container for, let's say, a User class, I would do so:

```
class Container
{
    protected $parameters;

    public function set($index, $value)
    {
        $this->parameters[$index] = $value;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return new User($this->paramaters['id'], $this->parameters['nickname']);
    }
}

$container = new Container();
$container->set('id', 1);
$container->set('nickname', 'Bob');
$container->getUser();
```

This works fine. But now, here is an other case: Let's say that now, instead of a User class, I want a Post class, for each post, I will need to set their title, text and date in the constructor, and each post shouldn't have the same parameters. In this case, is an dependency injection container adapted, if so, how should I achieve it without having a mess of a code?

**Edit:**

Will asked me my use case:

In my use case, I am actually doing this with a **Router** class that need to use **Route** instances. Each instantiated **Route** need to be passed two arguments: the *pattern* and the *callback*. So each time I ask my container to create a Route instance, it shouldn't use for all **Route**s the same pattern and callback, but a new pair of them (pattern + callback). How should I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Your goal here is to create a *Shared Abstraction* which can be injected into the code that depends on its data. There's two approaches you can take, and I think you're mixing the two already.

1. **A Generic Dependency-Injection Container** - In this case, we make a very generic object that can store and retrieve other objects. An example is here:

   ```
   <?php

   class Container
   {
       protected $dependencies = array();

       public function get($key)
       {
           return isset($this->dependencies[$key]) ? $this->dependencies[$key] : null;
       }

       public function register($key, $value)
       {
           $this->dependencies[$key] = $value;
       }
   }
   ```

   You can then use the container like this:

   ```
   $container = new Container();
   $container->register('user', new User(1, 'Bob'));
   $container->register('somethingElse', new SomethingElse(42));
   ```

   And then you can just pass `$container` to another function, method, or object, where you can do:

   ```
   $user = $container->get('user');
   ```

   There are also many Open Source containers you can use like [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), or [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/).
2. **A Domain-Specific Shared Abstraction** - Another approach is to make a specific shared abstraction, like, in your case, a `UserPost` perhaps:

   ```
   <?php

   class UserPost
   {
       protected $user;
       protected $post;

       public function __construct(User $user, Post $post)
       {
           $this->user = $user;
           $this->post = $post;
       }

       public function getUser()
       {
           return $this->user;
       }

       public function getPost()
       {
           return $this->post;
       }
   }
   ```

   You can then simply inject the `UserPost` and call `$userPost->getUser()` / `$userPost->getPost()`. The second method here is basically as simple as coming up with a name for the combination of data items you wish to pass. I prefer this approach, as it makes the code more readable, but this is a matter of opinion. I prefer to have my classnames correspond to "what I think of this object as" in plain English. This also aligns more closely with the core-OO principals of abstraction, in my opinion. But, the generic containers in Option 1 is an approach used successfully by many.

Comment: Thank you for the awnser, but it doesn't awnsers my question, maybe I didn't explain my problem correctly. I'll take your 'getPost' method of your second example to explain. In my case, each time I want to call 'getPost', I want it to return a new instance of my Post class, this can be easily done by making the 'post' property a callback that would return a new instance of Post. But each time I want to a new instance of Post with 'getPost', I want to pass it different arguments, how should I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll add a note about that. What you need is a [Factory](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) (Design Pattern). I'm not sure that combining a DI container with a Factory is the best idea. Better might be to just store the *parameters* in the DI container and then use a `PostFactory` or `UserPostFactory` to actually instantiate these objects. Is there ever a case where you'll want to reuse the same `Post` object (instantiate it once and cache it)? Can you edit and explain your use case a bit more maybe? :)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post to explain my case. Thank you for the quick awnser!

Comment: There you go, I explained my use case at the bottom of my question.